# What does :2 mean when running Docker registry?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

In every tutorial I've found regarding Docker registry there is a command like this:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name registry registry:2
```

Tag *2* is used here. Why? I've tried *registry* without the tag and it also worked.
I think it has something to do with different API (?) of Docker registry but I am not sure.

Comment: maybe the 2nd tag is the default tag for the registry? When you don't specify the tag, it goes for default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct! the tag `2` represents Docker Registry v2 Implementation which is also Docker Registry HTTP API V2. which solves several problems that were in `V1` and introduce new features as described in the following links:

- [Docker Registry HTTP API V2](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/)
- [More about Registry 2.0](https://github.com/docker/distribution#more-about-registry-20)

By removing `2` then docker goes to a default tag called `latest` which currently points to the following tags `2.7.1`, `2.7`, `2`.
So when Docker Inc. releases Registry `V3`, the `latest` tag will point to `V3` and in case you need `V2` in specific you have to add it to your command explicitly. You can check [the available tags for the registry image](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry?tab=tags)

Answer (score 2):

You are right about the API. From [github.com/docker/distribution](https://github.com/docker/distribution):

> ## Distribution
>
> The Docker toolset to pack, ship, store, and deliver content.
>
> This repository's main product is the **Docker Registry 2.0** implementation for storing and distributing Docker images. It supersedes the [docker/docker-registry](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry) project with a new API design, focused around security and performance.

and:

> #### registry
>
> An implementation of the [Docker Registry HTTP API V2](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/spec/api.md) for use with docker 1.6+.

---

### Why both work?

When you `docker pull registry` you actually `pull` `registry:latest` and it has the same digest as `registry:2`. Demo:

```
$ docker pull registry
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/registry
169185f82c45: Already exists 
046e2d030894: Pull complete 
188836fddeeb: Pull complete 
832744537747: Pull complete 
7ceea07e80be: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:870474507964d8e7d8c3b53bcfa738e3356d2747a42adad26d0d81ef4479eb1b
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry:latest

$ docker pull registry:2
2: Pulling from library/registry
Digest: sha256:870474507964d8e7d8c3b53bcfa738e3356d2747a42adad26d0d81ef4479eb1b
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry:2
```